# Attribute specifier error in LINQ to XML / Excel / XDocument code

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to use LINQ to XML to create an Excel spreadsheet.  I created a template spreadsheet, exported it to XML, pasted the XML into my code and then began to edit it.  When I try to create a set of XElements using LINQ, I get these errors:

[image: Code errors]

The first squiggle under `<Cell>` says "attribute specifier is not a complete statement"

The second under ss says "'>' expected"

The third under Type says "'Type' is a type and cannot be used in an expression"

Ignore the error under "Lot 1..." I will be putting an expression hole there.

The squiggle under `</Cell>` says "Identifier expected"

I have all of the Import statements that I should need for this code.

Any suggestions why these errors arise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the inline XML after select has to be a single element, and you have two.  Try putting them inside a root element.

Comment: Thanks. The next level up looks like this: `<Row ss:Index="4"> <Cell ss:StyleID="s21"><Data ss:Type="String">Primary Sample:</Data></Cell> <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Lot 1(LIMS 1)</Data></Cell> <Cell ss:StyleID="s21"><Data ss:Type="String">Primary Sample:</Data></Cell> <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Lot 3 (LIMS 3)</Data></Cell> </Row>` There are no errors here. Does this help?

Comment: Phoog's answer led me to the cause of the problem.  I did need to include the <Row> element along with the <Cell> elements.  I also needed to remove the ss:Index="4" from the Row characteristics.